# Angular how to get a value back from a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i am quite new to angular and am trying to get a value froma  button displayed in the html via a function.
the button layout is:

```
`<button class="btn" id="btn-gold"   (click)="value(9)"              
name="mybutton" value="9">`
9
```

i am also calling the function in the html file like following: {{ value() }}.

this is my setup in the .ts file:

`public value(a) {
    console.log(a);
    return a;
    }`

sadly i am not able to get any value displayed in my html file. i can see this in the console:

- 7
- scoring.component.ts:18 undefined
- scoring.component.ts:18 undefined

now to the question. why am i not able to see the value in my .html file as i can see the number in my console, and secondly why am i also getting per click two undefined values with it :/

chears,
ArcherMark

Comment: Maybe because you need to pass a parameter to the function. Something like `{{ value(7) }}`...

Comment: @miselking i have tired this and it had no effect on the outcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a property value in your TypeScript

```
value: number;
```

and have a function to set the value

```
setValue(value: number) {
  this.value = value;
}
```

Now you can set the value with a button in the template

```
<button class="btn" id="btn-gold" (click)="setValue(9)" name="mybutton" value="9">
```

and display the value with a template binding

```
{{ value }}
```

Comment: Could have just <button class="btn" (click)="value=9" name="mybutton" value="9"> -->> {{ value }}.

Answer (score 1):

If you do something like {{ value() }} you are calling a method not a property so angular is gonna evaluate that expression every time it checks for changes, which is associated with the DoCheck lifecycle hook thats why the console log prints 2 times the value,

The solution is to convert value into a property and have a getter and a setter and use two way data binding.